# C# Chamada de metodo e variavel

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um quis em c#, fiz os metodos de perguntas porem na hora de verificar as alternativas corretas não esta gravando a pontuação na variavel pontos, o que estou fazendo de errado?

```html
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Quiz
{
    public partial class QuizComidas : Form
    {
        private int pontos = 0;

        public QuizComidas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
     
        }
        
        private void Pergunta2()
        {
            LblQuestao.Text = "Questão 2";
            lblPergunta.Text = "Em que Pais foi inventada a feijoada?";
            lblResposta.Text = "";

            btbAlt1.Text = "Italia";
            btbAlt2.Text = "Brasil";
            btbAlt3.Text = "Argentina";
            btbAlt4.Text = "Portugal";

            btbAlt1.Checked = false;
            btbAlt2.Checked = false;
            btbAlt3.Checked = false;
            btbAlt4.Checked = false;

            if (btbAlt4.Checked == true)
            {

                pontos += 1;
                pontos++;
            }

        } 

        private void Pergunta3()
        {
            LblQuestao.Text = "Questão 3";
            lblPergunta.Text = "O acarajé foi inventado aonde?";
            lblResposta.Text = "";

            btbAlt1.Text = "Bahia";
            btbAlt2.Text = "Maranhão";
            btbAlt3.Text = "São Paulo";
            btbAlt4.Text = "Salvador";

            btbAlt1.Checked = false;
            btbAlt2.Checked = false;
            btbAlt3.Checked = false;
            btbAlt4.Checked = false;

            if (btbAlt2.Checked == true)
            {

                pontos = pontos + 1;
            }
        }

        private void Pergunta4()
        {
            LblQuestao.Text = "Questão 4";
            lblPergunta.Text = "A Caipirinha tem "+"\n"+
                                "origem de qual estado brasileiro?";
        

            btbAlt1.Text = "Mato Grosso";
            btbAlt2.Text = "Acre";
            btbAlt3.Text = "São Paulo";
            btbAlt4.Text = "Rio Grande Do Sul";

            btbAlt1.Checked = false;
            btbAlt2.Checked = false;
            btbAlt3.Checked = false;
            btbAlt4.Checked = false;

            if (btbAlt3.Checked == true)
            {

                pontos = pontos + 1;
            }
        }

        private void Pergunta5()
        {
            LblQuestao.Text = "Questão 5";
            lblPergunta.Text = "Você vai na região Sul do país e come"+"\n"+
                                "uma fruta Bergamota."+"\n"+
                                "Uma Bergamota é o mesmo que:";

            btbAvançar.Text = "Finalizar";
            btbAlt1.Text = "Laranja";
            btbAlt2.Text = "Maça";
            btbAlt3.Text = "Mexerica";
            btbAlt4.Text = "Uva";

            btbAlt1.Checked = false;
            btbAlt2.Checked = false;
            btbAlt3.Checked = false;
            btbAlt4.Checked = false;

            if (btbAlt3.Checked == true)
            {

                pontos = pontos + 1;
            }
        }


        private void lblPergunta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btbCorreto_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void QuizComidas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void btbAvançar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if(LblQuestao.Text == "Questão 1")
            {
                Pergunta2();
                

            } 
           
              else  if (LblQuestao.Text == "Questão 2") 
            {
                Pergunta3();
       
            }
                else if(LblQuestao.Text == "Questão 3")
            {
                Pergunta4();
            }
                else if(LblQuestao.Text == "Questão 4")
            {
                Pergunta5();
              
            }
            else if(btbAvançar.Text == "Finalizar")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sua Pontuação: "+ pontos, "Pontuação",
             MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Vitoria, pelo que percebi, ao clicar no botão de avançar você está chamando o método da questão seguinte, porém ela ainda não foi respondida, por isso não grava as respostas. Você testou se o lblQuestao.Text é a questão 1 executou o método da questão dois, porém você respondeu a questão 1 e não a 2. No seu if da questão 1, chame o método da questão 1 e avance para a questão 2, no seu if da questão 2 chame o método da questão 2 e avance para a questão 3 e assim por diante...

Comment: Vou tentar, obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro problema é que você está verificando a resposta no mesmo momento em que está criando a pergunta. Como foi dito nos comentários do Adjair.

Você não deve checar a resposta nos métodos Pergunta1(), Pergunta2(), etc...

Estes métodos devem ser responsáveis apenas por criar as perguntas.

O segundo problema é que uma vez que você está compartilhando os botões de resposta entre todas as perguntas, a resposta correta vai depender da pergunta corrente.

Portanto crie uma variável chamada `private int respostaCorreta;` e em cada método de criação das perguntas, armazene qual o botão que possui a resposta correta para esta pergunta. 
Por exemplo no método `Pergunta2()` atribua `respostaCorreta = 4;` no método `Pergunta3()` atribua `respostaCorreta = 2;` e assim por diante

Resolvido isto, implemente os eventos click dos quatro botões de resposta e verifique se o botão clicado é o correspondente armazenado na variável respostaCorreta. Caso positivo incremente os pontos `pontos++;`

Ex:

```
 private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (respostaCorreta == 1)
    {
        pontos++;
    }
 }

 private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (respostaCorreta == 2)
    {
        pontos++;
    }
 }
```

e assim por diante.

PS: Verifique o nome dos métodos pois os controles tem um padrão de nome e os métodos outro (btbAlt1 e radioButton1_CheckedChanged) o metodo deveria se chamar btbAlt1_CheckedChanged

Comment: Muito obrigada, agora esta contando e esta tudo certinho